# Mongo indexing on nested object

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, go, nosql

My mongodb collection's structure looke like this,

```
{
paymentTree: {
t1: { from: "id-123", to: "id-2334", },
t2: { from: "id-1443", to: "id-567", },
t3: { from: "id-76567", to: "id-2334", },
tn: { from: "id-12n", to: "id-233n", }
}
```

How can index field 'to' in paymentTree?

Comment: The same way you'd index on a "regular" field. What have you tried? What problems do you have? Post a [mcve].

Comment: here t1,t2...tn are dynamic key so how can ,map it when create index for the key 'to'?

Comment: You can't create index on "dynamic" keys. The property names must be "static". If you're in such a situation, change the model to have `propName`-`propValue` pairs, which you _can_ index.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to create index in dynamic object key,

If you want to achieve anyway then I would suggest if you could transform your schema structure to [The Attribute Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern),

- change `paymentTree` object type to array type,
- change object to array in key-value pairs, `k` for tree's dynamic key and `v` for `{ from, to }` object,

```
{
  paymentTree: [
      {
        "k": "t1",
        "v": { "from": "id-123", "to": "id-2334" }
      },
      {
        "k": "t2",
        "v": { "from": "id-1443", "to": "id-567" }
      },
      {
        "k": "t3",
        "v": { "from": "id-76567", "to": "id-2334" }
      },
      {
        "k": "tn",
        "v": { "from": "id-12n", "to": "id-233n" }
      }
  ]
}
```

#### Benefits of this structure:

- **Create [Multikey Single Field Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#multikey-indexes) on `to`:**

  You can create multikey indexes on array fields that contain nested objects,

  ```
  db.collection.createIndex({ "paymentTree.v.to": 1 });
  ```
- **Create [Multikey Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#index-arrays-with-embedded-documents) on `k` and `to`:**

  ```
  db.collection.createIndex({ "paymentTree.k": 1, "paymentTree.v.to": 1 });
  ```
- **Push object to array:**

  You can insert object to `paymentTree` array using `$push` in update methods (`updateOne` and `updateMany`).
- **Pull object from array:**

  You can remove specific object on the base of `k` from paymentTree array using `$pull` in update methods (`updateOne` and `updateMany`).
- **Match conditions:**

  You can easily match conditions using conditional operators,

  - **Ex.1:**

  ```
  { "paymentTree.k": "t1" }
  ```

  - **Ex.2:**

  ```
  { "paymentTree.v.to": "id-2334" } // or { "paymentTree.v.from": "id-123" }
  ```

  - **Ex.3:**

  ```
  { 
    "paymentTree": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "k": "t1",
        "v.to": "id-2334"   // or "v.from": "id-123"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- **How can i easily select like paymentTree.t1, ..:**

  - **In Query:**

    - There is a operator called [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), you can convert `paymentTree` array to object in projection stages (`$project`, `$addFields`, `$set`) see [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DX0N61JZnuY),
    - The [`find()` and `findOne()` projection can accept aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) expressions and syntax from MongoDB v4.4 projection consistent with aggregation’s `$project` stage,
  - **Outside Query:**

    - You need to convert `peymentTree` array to object format in your client side language (go, node.js, etc.).

Comment: Your prompt response would be highly appreciated.   here t1,t2...are transaction levels so how can i easily select like paymentTree.t1 or paymentTree.t2 from the code part otherwise i have to loop entire tree to pickup each level (t1,t2...)

Comment: i have added 2 more benefits at the end of the answer, that will solve your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
_, err = db.Comments.Indexes().CreateOne(db.Ctx, mongo.IndexModel{Keys: bson.M{"t1.to": 1}})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```