# Accessing dynamic properties added to mongoDb model using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have user expense model which have already some required expenses and optionally can add more expenses which i handled through dynamic properties adding to moongodb model  by setting true the strict flag in model. Dynamic properties are being added and saved to mongodb successfully .I am getting them back too but when i access it in javascript it gives undefined.I have spent hours but remain clueless. The model schema is following.

````
const {
  TRANSPORT,
  FOOD,
  PHONEBILL,
  UTILITIES,
  MISC,
  MONTHLY,
  WEEKLY,
  RENT,
} = require("../constants");
const semesterPlanSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    expense: {
      [RENT]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
      [FOOD]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
      [TRANSPORT]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
      [PHONEBILL]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
      [UTILITIES]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
      [MISC]: {
        amount: Number,
        duration: {
          type: String,
          enum: [WEEKLY, MONTHLY],
        },
      },
    },
    month: {
      type: Number,
      enum: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    },
    user_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
    // will be used in emergency fund request
    // to check which plan month is currently active(1-5)
    isActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    expired: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    grand_total: {
      type: Number,
    },
    start_date: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    strict: false,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("semesterplan", semesterPlanSchema);```
````

Comment: out of the scope, this looks more static schema rather than dynamic schema, i would suggest to change your schema to key-value pairs. recently i have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123924/8987128) for more information.

Comment: @turivishal . But like other attibutes inside expense object e.g [transport],i have added other dynamic properties which are been saved.and i am getting them back too loging it but when i access it i says undefined

Comment: the logged doc is ```{
  RENT: { amount: 2000, duration: 'MONTHLY' },
  FOOD: { amount: 1500, duration: 'WEEKLY' },
  TRANSPORT: { amount: 800, duration: 'WEEKLY' },
  PHONEBILL: { amount: 800, duration: 'MONTHLY' },
  UTILITIES: { amount: 800, duration: 'MONTHLY' },
  MISC: { amount: 800, duration: 'MONTHLY' },
  EXTRA: { amount: 300, duration: 'MONTHLY' },
  MOBILE_INSTALLMENT: { amount: 999, duration: 'MONTHLY' }
}```

Answer (score 0):

To read properties added with help of strict:false, you should use `get([path])` method on the document.

Let's say that your document is read and stored into the variable `semesterPlan`.
And the name of the new dynamic property is for example `otherExpenses`,
then to read the property value you should use `semesterPlan.get("otherExpenses")`

Comment: Basically i  am getting the keys from expense object which in turn are objects and then i iterate the keys and find their values for further processing in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand you well. I would only like to point out that documents in our case `semesterPlan` is an instance of Model `semesterplan`, and not the plain javascript object. To convert the document to the plain object you can use `semesterPlan.toObject()` or `semesterPlan.toJSON()`

Comment: I have tried almost everything nothing worked for me .so changed my database schema.Thanks for helping out.